# dnsmasq forwards local request despite domain-needed

Tags: dnsmasq

From a new Debian 11 installation, I use the following dnsmasq configuration

```
domain-needed
log-queries
no-resolv
no-hosts
server=8.8.8.8
```

So Dnsmasq should not forward a no-full qualified request to the server.

But when I run `host nowhere`, `/var/log/syslog` shows the following lines

```
Mar 11 20:52:42 gateway dnsmasq[3904]: query[A] nowhere from 127.0.0.1
Mar 11 20:52:42 gateway dnsmasq[3904]: config nowhere is NODATA-IPv4
Mar 11 20:52:42 gateway dnsmasq[3904]: query[AAAA] nowhere from 127.0.0.1
Mar 11 20:52:42 gateway dnsmasq[3904]: config nowhere is NODATA-IPv6
Mar 11 20:52:42 gateway dnsmasq[3904]: query[MX] nowhere from 127.0.0.1
Mar 11 20:52:42 gateway dnsmasq[3904]: forwarded nowhere to 8.8.8.8
```

So the request is forward to 8.8.8.8.

Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domain-needed` is only for A and AAAA queries. Your log shows only MX query forwarding.

> -D, --domain-needed
> Tells dnsmasq to never forward A or AAAA queries for plain names, without dots or domain parts, to upstream nameservers. If the name
> is not known from /etc/hosts or DHCP then a "not found" answer is returned.

Comment: Thanks Mak. I didn't know that host make a MX query.